# Is it possible to build ros without python, only C++ support?

Tags: ros, c++, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to build a minimal ros without having to install python. I use only native c++ nodes. The system has to run on a platform with minimal memory and should require as little space on the harddrive as possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201437/is-it-possible-to-build-ros-without-python,-only-c++-support?/) by [virgil85](https://answers.ros.org/users/21436/virgil85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No; you cannot install ROS without python. Many of the ROS tools, such as rostopic, are written in python, along with parts of the build system, such as the message generators.

It may be possible to install ROS on a larger development machine and use a toolchain such as [meta_ros](https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros) to cross-compile for your embedded system.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2